# Substring of filename in external command (bang)

Tags: external-command

Is it possible to execute bash string manipulations to the filename of the current file, represented by `%` in external commands from within vim?

**Example:**

I am editing a file `myfile.txt`. Using `:! command %`, I can execute a `command` on `myfile.txt` from within vim. For instance, to copy `myfile.txt` to `myfile.ext` (simply change the extension), I can write `:! cp % myfile.ext`. But there is some redundancy, and I'd like to deduce `myfile.ext` from `%` (and avoid writing `myfile`).

In bash, if the name `myfile.txt` is contained in the variable `$var`, I can write `cp $var ${var%txt}ext` for instance.

Is there a way to mimick this in vim? Of course, I cannot write `:! cp % ${%%txt}ext`... though it is what I'd like to be able to!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to shell out to save a copy with a different extension. Try either of the following, both of which use the "root" `:r` modifier to strip the extension from the filename:

```
:w %:r.ext
:sav %:r.ext
```

The former will save a copy, but leave you editing the original. The latter will switch over so that you are now editing the copy.

See `:h filename-modifiers` for details of the many different modifiers Vim provides.

Comment: You can also use `:w %<.ext`